# Cannot Use Whole Disk after Disk Upgrade on my VPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, vps, partition

I upgraded the disk size of my VPS from 20GB to 40GB. I cannot use this newly added 20GB. `fdisk -l` shows 40GB but `du -h` shows 20GB!

```
root@ubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  656K  385M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   16G  2.5G  87% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           385M     0  385M   0% /run/user/0


root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 38.2 GiB, 40961572864 bytes, 80003072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7a5a5ba2

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 80003038 80000991 38.2G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize the filesystem to match the new disk size.

Assuming this is an EXT filesystem then there should be a command called `resize2fs` that will do it, but this is a potentially dangerous task and is normally best done when booted from a rescue system. Given this is a VPS that is unlikely to be possible so make sure you have a good backup before starting.